# jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip is it stable?

Tags: jboss

It seems as if the jboss teams doesn't want to say that the Java 6 compile of Jboss AS 4.2.3 is a GA, they write that it shouyld be considered expiremental.

Anyone using it in production? we're using it in test and plan to move it to prod as it hasn't shown any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been running that same distribution (jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip) in production for several months now and it's been working like a champ.  However be aware of this issue in particular, it bit us in testing and would have killed us in production: (Add http://) jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBWEB-82 .  We've installed JBoss Native as a work around and it's been running great.

Answer (score 1):

We have now been running it for a quarter of a year. Seems stable, apart from some strange logs from the transaction manager for unreceverable XA transactions, but we havn't been able to connect those log entries to any application errors.
So it seems stable.